# How to use PublishBuildArtifacts for publishing one file without directory-tree?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, publish, azure-artifacts

My Build-Pipeline builds my artefact to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)\s\out\make\squirrel.windows\x64\simSetup-1.0.0.exe`.

I want to publish this file as a pipeline-artifact.

For this, I have craeted this two tasks in my pipeline:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    Contents: '**/simSetup-*.exe'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: sim'
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: simSetup
```

This is working but it will include the whole directory-tree in the published zip-file. How can I only include the file `simSetup-1.0.0.exe`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should achieve your requirements:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    Contents: '**/simSetup-*.exe'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    flattenFolders: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: sim'
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: simSetup
```

This is my folder structure:

[image]

Successfully clean the tree structure during pipeline run via the setting:

[image]